# strategies for colouring scatterplot according to residual distance from regression line- over a range of variables

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a dataframe in which I want to iteratively plot each column against the first column. And I want to make a sactterplot and to colour the points in accordance with their distance from the regression line.

```
    head(data)
       data nucleosome  H3K27me3   H3K9me3
[1,] -20000   4.612515 0.3502755 0.4066719
[2,] -19999   4.619391 0.3500934 0.4070110
[3,] -19998   4.622314 0.3496383 0.4066719
[4,] -19997   4.619391 0.3497293 0.4060786
[5,] -19996   4.618532 0.3490921 0.4049767
[6,] -19995   4.620423 0.3490011 0.4047225
```

Based on the following link: https://www.r-bloggers.com/visualising-residuals/ 
I have tried this and achieved the following:
[image]

This was done as follows:

```
for(i in seq(2,ncol(data))){
  print(colnames(data)[i])
  fit=lm(paste0('heterochromatin~', colnames(data)[i]), data=as.data.frame(data))
  #print(ggplotRegression(fit))
  g=ggplot(data = as.data.frame(data),aes_string(x=colnames(data)[i], y='nucleosome'))+
  geom_point(aes(color=abs(residuals(fit))))+
  geom_smooth(method=lm, col="blue")+
  scale_color_continuous(low = "red", high = "black")+ labs(color='Residual distance') +
  #annotate("text", x = min(data[,i]), y=max(nucleosome), label = paste("R^2 is", format(summary(fit)$adj.r.squared, digits=3)))+
  geom_text(label = paste("R^2 is", format(summary(fit)$adj.r.squared, digits=3)), x = min(data[,i]), y=max(nucleosome), hjust='inward')+
  theme(axis.text=element_text(size=12),axis.title=element_text(size=14))
  #legend("topleft", bty="n", legend=paste("R2 is", format(summary(fit)$adj.r.squared, digits=3)))
  png(paste0(colnames(data)[i],'_enhanced_ggplot.png'))
  print(g)
  dev.off()
}
```

However I would much prefer to separate the residuals factorially so that the distances from the regression line are more obvious like below:

[image]

```
for(i in seq(2,ncol(data))){
  print(colnames(data)[i])
  fit=lm(paste0('heterochromatin~', colnames(data)[i]), data=as.data.frame(data))
  cols=kmeans(abs(residuals(fit)), centers = 4)$cluster
  g=ggplot(data = as.data.frame(data),aes_string(x=colnames(data)[i], y='nucleosome'))+
  geom_point(aes(color=cols))+
  geom_smooth(method=lm, col="blue")+
  scale_color_continuous()+labs(color='Residual distance') 
  annotate("text", x = min(data[,i]), y=max(nucleosome), label = paste("R^2 is", format(summary(fit)$adj.r.squared, digits=3)))
  #legend("topleft", bty="n", legend=paste("R2 is", format(summary(fit)$adj.r.squared, digits=3)))
  png(paste(i,'regression.png'))
  print(g)
  dev.off()
}
```

to do this I used k-means to separate the residual distances:

```
   cols=kmeans(abs(residuals(fit)), centers = 4)$cluster
```

But as you can see from above the points are not indexed correctly, the points closest to the line are supposed to be coloured the darkest as you can see from the legend. also the colouring is inconsistent between the plots.. for some the lightest points are closest to the regression line for others not....

How can I get kmeans/ some other mechanism to colour the plots correctly?

I have also tried

```
rbPal <- colorRampPalette(c('red','blue'))
cols<- rbPal(10)[as.numeric(cut(abs(residuals(fit)),breaks = 10))]
```

but I get the error:

```
Error: Discrete value supplied to continuous scale
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the residuals from the model object to get the distance of each point from the regression line. For example:

```
library(tidyverse)

m1 = lm(mpg ~ wt, data=mtcars)

ggplot(mtcars %>% mutate(resid=abs(resid(m1)),
                         fitted=fitted(m1))) +
  geom_line(aes(wt, fitted)) + 
  geom_point(aes(wt, mpg, colour=resid)) +
  scale_colour_gradient(low="blue", high="red") +
  theme_classic() +
  labs(x="Weight", y="MPG", colour="Residuals")
```

[image]

If you want discrete colors, turn the residuals into a factor:

```
ggplot(mtcars %>% mutate(resid=cut(abs(resid(m1)), 4),
                         fitted=fitted(m1))) +
  geom_line(aes(wt, fitted)) + 
  geom_point(aes(wt, mpg, colour=resid)) +
  scale_colour_manual(values=hcl(0,100,seq(70,20,len=4))) +
  theme_classic() +
  labs(x="Weight", y="MPG", colour="Residuals")
```

[image]

To do this for every column in the data frame, we'll use `map` to run the same code for each column. The output of the code below is a list where each list element is a plot of the regression results for `mpg` vs. each column of `mtcars`:

```
plot.list = names(mtcars)[-grep("mpg", names(mtcars))] %>%
  map(function(var) { 

    m1 = lm(paste0("mpg ~", var) , data=mtcars)

    ggplot(mtcars %>% mutate(resid=cut(abs(resid(m1)), 4),
                             fitted=fitted(m1))) +
      geom_line(aes_string(var, "fitted")) + 
      geom_point(aes_string(var, "mpg", colour="resid")) +
      scale_colour_manual(values=hcl(0,100,seq(70,20,len=4))) +
      theme_classic() +
      labs(x=var, y="MPG", colour="Residuals")
  })
```

If you want a stable colour mapping across all plots (i.e., a given residual value always gets mapped to the same color) then you need to find the maximum residual value across all the regressions. For example:

```
# Find largest residual value among all regressions
max.resid = names(mtcars)[-grep("mpg", names(mtcars))] %>%
  map_dbl(~ max(resid(lm(paste0("mpg ~", .x) , data=mtcars)))) %>% max
```

Now we use `max.resid` when setting the `breaks` when we turn `resid` into a factor:

```
plot.list = names(mtcars)[-grep("mpg", names(mtcars))] %>%
  map(function(var) { 

    m1 = lm(paste0("mpg ~", var) , data=mtcars)

    ggplot(mtcars %>% mutate(resid=cut(abs(resid(m1)), breaks=seq(0, max.resid, length=5)),
                             fitted=fitted(m1))) +
      geom_line(aes_string(var, "fitted")) + 
      geom_point(aes_string(var, "mpg", colour="resid")) +
      scale_colour_manual(values=hcl(0,100,seq(70,20,len=6)), drop=FALSE) +
      theme_classic() +
      labs(x=var, y="MPG", colour="Residuals")
  })
```